# Coldfusion: Index of Element in 2D Array

Tags: arrays, coldfusion

I was working with a 2D array this past week and no matter what I tried, I was not able to access the data elements in the array.  Coldfusion kept returning "Complex/simple value" errors or index of elemnet in position 1, etc..

I moved on a found a different method using a struct, but I am curious as to why I could not get the correct index.

I was trying to read in a text file:

```
<cfset myarr = arraynew(2) />

<cffile action="read" file="#filepath#" variable="filedata" />

    <cfloop list="#filedata#" index="line" delimiters="#chr(13)##chr(10)#">

        <cfset line = trim( line ) />

        <cfif line contains "routing number">
           <cfset arrayappend( myarr[1], listlast( line, ":" )) />
        <cfelseif line contains "account number">
           <cfset arrayappend( myarr[2], listlast( line, ":" )) />
        </cfif>

        <cfloop index="j" from="1" to="#arraylen( myarr )#" step="1">
           <cfoutput>
               #listgetat( myarr[line][j] )#
           </cfoutput>
        </cfloop>
   </cfloop>
```

Now, if I dump out my array, the array looks correct

```
array
1
    1 999999999
    2 111111111

array
2
    1 12345678
    2 987654321
```

However, the nested loop above does not get the correct position of the element in the index and I do not understand why.

Thanks for any help or insight you can provide.

Comment: The above does not compile. "Parameter validation error for the LISTGETAT function" Do you have the original code?

Comment: Your second loop doesn't make sense. If you are adding into myarr[1] and myarr[2], why are you getting index at [line][j] when line is a LINE of the file... not the line number. And j is looping over an arraylen of myarr, but wouldn't you want to know the length of myarr[1] or myarr[2] - Really need the original code, this is pretty messy.

Comment: Just an FYI - When looping line by line over a big file... you can just use this... it is cleaner and you dont have to worry about the delimiters etc.
    <cfloop file="#filepath#" index="line" > do stuff </cfloop>

Comment: I suggest baby steps.  Start by declaring a 2D array and seeing if the arrayappend function works at all.  It might not.

Comment: How about every time you read a row, use a ListToArray() on it?

Comment: To me it looks like that first array dimension should be a struct, not an array. What do the first and second elements of that array represent?

Comment: Yes, I ended up using a struct.  I was just curious to understand why I could not access the index of the elements in the array.  When I dumped out the array, it looked fine.  Thank you all for your comments.  next time, I'll try loop file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic just doesn't make any sense:

1. Your second loop is trying to loop over the array whilst you're still building it (which is not impossible, but doesn't seem like what you want to be doing;
2. you are looping over the length of the first dimension of the array (`arraylen(myarr)`), but then using that variable as an index in the *second* dimension of the array.
3. I strongly suspect you want a struct as that first dimension, not an array. What is the nature of the data?

Also, as someone else alluded to, pls post your *actual* code. That cannot be your code as it doesn't even compile, let alone run.

This answer doesn't get you to where you want to end up (because you haven't really defined that clearly), but it explains why you're definitely not getting there.

Can I suggest you revise your question to describe what you actually want to achieve, and revise your code in accordance with all the suggestions in the comments first. And then post code which actually compiles.

Comment: A text file of batched ACH data.  I do not have the actual code to post because I ended up going in a different direction and scrapped the array code I had been working on.  Thanks for the answer.  I don't want to waste anyone else's time on this question.

Comment: Righto. So put an answer in & close the question, or delete it then. Don't leave it hanging around, as people will think it still needs answering. Recommend just deleting it.